# Set an Image on the Current Location

Tags: android, dictionary, navigation, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Since the last two weeks i am developing a Navigation App.
I want to set an Pointer that is showing me the current Location.
How I can make this without using the Marker ? Or did I have to use the Marker ?

Comment: Which library/framework?

Comment: I use 2 libs From osm.First osmdroid4.1.jar and osmbonuspack_v4.2.8 for use later the Roadmanager i want to display after i make a Point and when i use the Marker i am not able to use this it gives me an error --The constructor Marker(MapView) is undefined--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Marker startMarker = new Marker(mapView);
        startMarker.setPosition(gp);
        startMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(startMarker);
        mapView.invalidate();
        startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconcurrentlocation));
        startMarker.setTitle("Start point");
```

with this one u can set immag on yout cuurentLocation and the Important thing is that you have to import this

```
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Marker;
```

I hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the current location, you can use one of the following osmdroid Overlays:

- MyLocationOverlay or MyLocationNewOverlay: handling GPS positionning
- Or DirectedLocationOverlay: GPS position/direction/precision to handle yourself.

By the way, Marker(MapView) should be defined... Your OSMBonusPack lib is probably not installed properly.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer. i didnt installed something i only copy and paste it in the folder lib. Did I forget something to do?

Comment: Probably. Have a look here: http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude

Comment: I follow this one too.